# Is it possible to have separate animations, with independent timelines?

Tags: animation

I've a scene with several objects that have (keyframe) animations attached to them. For clarity, think of a house with different doors and windows that can open and close independently of each other.

Right now, I've a single timeline that opens all the 'doors and windows' one by one. But I would like to be able to change when which animation plays when, independently of each other. I would like to, for example, open two doors at once, while all others stay closed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, open the timeline and the dope sheet:

[image]

On the bottom bar of the dope sheet windon change the "mode" from "Dope sheet" to "Action". Select a door, add an action and call it like "Door 1" and animate it from frame 0 the door opening.

Repeat until you have all doors and windows opening at the same time (only the beggining, you can have different ending times).

Then change the Dope Sheet window to the NLA Editor where you can see all actions:

[image]

Press the icon of the down arrows and you'll see that it creates a box, repeat for every object and then, choosing a box and pressing "g" you can move the box freely.

Comment: While I'm sure this answer is pointing to the right direction, the information is too sparse for me to transform my (existing) animations into action. Could you go into a little more detail?

Comment: If you already have the animation, go to the NLA Editor, and press the down arrow icon on the name of the object animated to tranform the animation into a block.